# Save key, value of model does not get saved in scope and duplicates input fields

Tags: angularjs

This is my model:

```
{ aktuell: { N5: '8', Auftragsnr: 123 },
  historie:
   [
    { some data },
    { more data }
   ]
};
```

I have this html code:

```
 <ul>
 <li>
        <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friends[0].aktuell" ng-show="key != '_id' && key != '__v'">
            {{key}}    
        </span>
 </li>
 <br>
 <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friend.aktuell" ng-show="key != '_id' && key != '__v'">
            <input type="text" ng-model="value">
        </span>
        <button ng-click="save(friend)" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

**What happens:**

When I click on Save, the controller gets correctly fired (and does API requests, etc), however any new value entered into the input field does not get saved inside the friend model (scope). I tried Chrome Batarang, and when entering a value a new input field, the scope is not changed, see screenshot:

[image]

**Expected Behaviour:**

The expected behaviour is to save the new "N5" value inside the "aktuell" member of the friend model.

**Update:** Fixed the "double input" field error in the meanwhile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friend.aktuell" ng-show="key != '_id' && key != '__v'">
            <input type="text" ng-model="friend.aktuell[key]">
        </span>
        <button ng-click="save(friend)" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </li>
```

Comment: As @dhavalcengg's answer points out you need to specify where the "value" is in the friend object. So in your example you'd want ng-model="friend.akuell['N5']" on your input

Comment: @catalyst294 If you do something like that, it will be hard coded.. and we do not want that.. :):)

Comment: I was not suggesting to hard code it, just trying to the your answer back to the example in the question with a little bit more of an explanation.

Comment: That's what I thought. Well @dhavalcengg if you could add some explanation I would most certainly read it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ng-model="value"` to `friend.aktuell[key]`

The variable `value` is not referencing the '8' of "N5" in your "friend.aktuell" object, but instead it is a "copy" of it because '8' or '123' or 'test' is a string/number (immutable primitives) and not an object (mutable object).

Assignment to immutable primitives are not references (in Javascript strings are also considered to be immutable primitives).

`key`, `value` are scope variables that Angular creates internally when you use `ng-repeat` within the scope that each repeated item (`span` in you example) gets of its own.

To illustrate, assume that `ng-repeat` simply does the following,

```
for (var k in friend.aktuell) {
  if (friend.aktuell.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    var key = k;
    var value = friend.aktuell[k];
  }
}
```

Here modifying `value` will update `friend.aktuell[k]` only if `friend.aktuell[k]` is a mutable object.